# how to assign value of light year in java datatype

Tags: java, numbers

How can I assign value of light year in meters in java to datatype, it seems it is too long.

For example:- 9,460,730,777,119,564 is value in mtrs for 1 light year

Comment: `long lightYearInMeters = 9_460_730_777_119_564L;`

Comment: Try [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) if even long is not enough

Comment: Do you need to account for relativity?  Trick question: The speed of light is constant in all reference frames (just wanted to actually use my physics knowledge for something constructive).

Comment: java.math.BigInteger

Comment: Using `double` instead of `long` would be a better choice:
`double lightYearInMeters = 9.460730777119564E+15;`

Answer (score 2):

The `Long` datatype in standard java 2^63-1 digits, so the speed of light in meters should fit

Answer (score 1):

You can use Long for it.

```
Long lightYearsInMeters = new Long("9460730777119564");
System.out.println(lightYearsInMeters);
```